# pipe rrd to a new directory

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, dump

I am chrooted and running out of drive space, so I mounted back to the host drive which has plenty of space but cannot seem to redirect the outputted data to my empty drive

```
[root@localhost rra]# ls /mnt/maindrv/
cacti-0.8.8b  cacti-0.8.8b.tar.gz  cacti2.tar  cactidb
[root@localhost rra]# for i in `ls *.rrd`; do rrdtool dump $i > '/mnt/maindrv/'.$i.'xml'; done
[root@localhost rra]# ls /mnt/maindrv/
cacti-0.8.8b  cacti-0.8.8b.tar.gz  cacti2.tar  cactidb
[root@localhost rra]# df -h /mnt/maindrv/
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-home
                       97G  1.5G   96G   2% /mnt/maindrv
```

How do I properly output my dump to `/mnt/maindrv/` ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the -a flag to your ls command to show 'hidden' files?  Your filenames all begin with a dot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you overlooked something here:

```
for i in `ls *.rrd`; do rrdtool dump $i > '/mnt/maindrv/'.$i.'xml'; done
```

In some languages the `.` is used to concatenate variables, but in Bash it's a literal dot.
So for example if you have a file `hello.rrd`, then the command will put the dump in:

```
/mnt/maindrv/.hello.rrd.xml
```

Since the file starts with a dot, `ls /mnt/maindrv/` will not list it, even though it's there.

Another thing, you shouldn't loop over `ls *.rrd` but simply `*.rrd`. 
This is not related to your question, but a bad practice.

This should do what you need, cleaner and better:

```
for i in *.rrd; do rrdtool dump "$i" > "/mnt/maindrv/$i.xml"; done
```